# iOS Device Audio outputs enumeration

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have an iphone 4s and an ipod touch.
The iphone has two available audio outputs ( speaker and ear ).

The ipod touch has just the speaker.

How can I enumerate which outputs the iOS device has available and detect if the output is the speaker output or the ear output ?

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `AVFoundation` to query information about the current route's output.

```
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
AVAudioSessionRouteDescription *route = [session currentRoute];
NSLog(@"%@", route.outputs); // outputs contains an array of AVAudioSessionPortDescription objects
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008240-CH1-SW111

At the lowest level you have each `AVAudioSessionPortDescription` objects which contains all the information you should need.